# simple ajax POST does not execute php function

Tags: php, ajax

Im trying to execute an php function with ajax, but the function does not answer,
If i use chrome to see the network result ill get this

**Edit : Im running this local with WAMP**

```
manageusers.php
/geopedia/core
POST
200
OK
text/html
jquery-1.10.1.min.js:6
Script
850 B
625 B
7 ms
4 ms
```

So shouldn't that work ?

Ajax function

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#facebook').click(function() { 
        var first_name = $('#first_name').val();
        var last_name = $('#last_name').val();
        var username = $('#username').val();

        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'core/manageusers.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                facebook:first_name,
                last_name:last_name,
                username:username

            },
        });
    });
});
```

Eventhandler

```
if(isset($_POST['facebook'])){ 
echo("inside");
include_once('core/class.users.php');
$users = new Users();

$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name  = $_POST['last_name'];
$username   = $_POST['username'];

$fb_user = $users->fb_user($first_name,$last_name,$username);
}
```

Comment: Your PHP handler just sets a variable, it doesn't do anything that should have any permanent result. How can you tell it's not being run?

Comment: `.html()` should be `.val()` and also facebook:first_name, is wrong due to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you find your error:

```
        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'core/manageusers.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                facebook:first_name,
                last_name:last_name,
                username:username,

            },
            success: function(mydata) {
                alert(mydata);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Eventhandler

```
<?php
//if(isset($_POST['facebook'])){ 
//echo("inside");
//include_once('core/class.users.php');
//$users = new Users();

$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name  = $_POST['last_name'];
$username   = $_POST['username'];

echo 'You sent: First: [' .$first_name. ']<br>'Last: [' .'$last_name. '] etc.';

//$fb_user = $users->fb_user($first_name,$last_name,$username);
```

Comment: Well honestly I don't think the function even enter my php file. Nothing is being executed . wtf :(

Comment: I got, now i get a bunch of errors here, the funny part is that if i use a common form method="post" the eventhandler works like a charm.

Comment: Did you try the changes I suggest above? They (1) make your PHP file echo what is being sent to it, and (2) make your AJAX routine display what the PHP file echos. This will, at least, give you visual proof that the AJAX/PHP routines are working. From there, you can begin to narrow-down where your error is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the "success" parameter?

```
.ajax({ 
        url: 'core/manageusers.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            facebook:first_name,
            last_name:last_name,
            username:username,

        },
        success: function (result) {
             //insert some code here
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your PHP doesn't give any response;
2. Even if it did, your Javascript code doesn't seem to make any use of
   it;
3. There is a comma after the last part of the `data` property in your
   `$.ajax` call. IE doesn't like that;
4. Lastly, you're not giving any kind of response, except `"inside"`
   for all requests, regardless of success, and you're not doing anything to handle the
   response in your Javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

Revised repost of previously deleted answer:

If you are running this script locally, try setting the dataType parameter to text or json in the POST request:$.ajax({ url: 'core/manageusers.php', type: 'POST', dataType: 'text', data: { .......

@Alfie Yes im actually running this locally. good you mention it. I tried to add dataType, both json and text but no luck. – Dymond

I have had similar nightmares in the past. It is down to a network security feature: Cross Domain Policy File. Wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

I found that in IE (but not firefox when I tested), setting the dataType to 'text' during jQuery request (as described above) worked. I also used the `success:...` return parameter as others have suggested. Otherwise, try creating a crossdomain.xml file and placing it in your root directory.

A 'loose' (allows everything) version of this would look like:

```
`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all" />
    <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" />
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>`
```